# Intersection Point of Vector Equation of a Line and Plane

Tags: vector-spaces

I am working on this problem:

Find the intersection point of **l**(t)= (7t+7, 7, -t)
and the ZY Plane.

I also attempted the problem with the XY plane instead of ZY.

This got me thinking about when there will NOT be an intersection point. It seems like they should always exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $YZ$ plane $x=0$ and for $XY$ plane $z=0$. So yes you are correct we would find an intersection point for both the planes.

Comment: What would be an example where there isnt an intersection pt?

Comment: Like $l(t)=(2,2+2t,4)$ this is always parallel to the $YZ$ and $XY$ plane

Comment: Ah, idk why i didnt think of that